# How to handle user status in MySQL using sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, relational-database, rdbms

I have user's who's status could be **active,pending,rejected,de-active**,so what is appropriate way to handle status.

I have two scenarios in my mind
1.  i can handle it by **isPending,isRejected,isActive ,isDe-active** flags
2. i can use **status** flag and can pass **0,1,2,3** corresponding

so my question is what is **best way** to handle status in **MySql**, is there any other scenarios

if you know anyone who can help pleas tag them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using a status integer would be a better idea for the following reasons:

- Your users can only have one active status at a time, so having only one column enforces that constraint.
- In the case where you would like to add another status (for example, `expired`, if you want to create temporary users), multiple flags would require you to change your schema, as the single column solution would just require you to change your code.
- Checking the user status with the first solution requires you to check all these booleans.
- Changing the user status with the first solution requires you to update multiple columns as the other solution requires only one column to be updated.